# Listen for keypress events on dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating text inputs on my page via a button click. Everything is working great.

For all existing elements (elements that are rendered when the page loads) I am listening to the keypress event to add/remove a class like this:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='number'], input[type='search'], input[type='password'], input[type='tel'], textarea").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which != 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Again, all is well - when I type in an input - the class is added/removed accordingly.

When I click a button to add more fields (for example, "add another name") I would also like to listen to the keypress event. I have tried this but no luck.

```
$('body').on('click', $("input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='number'], input[type='search'], input[type='password'], input[type='tel'], textarea"), function (event) {
    if (event.which != 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to make dynamically created elements listen to keypress events? Thank you for any suggestion!

**EDIT**

For anyone else who finds this thread, here is what the final method looks like.

```
$('body').on('keypress', "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='number'], input[type='search'], input[type='password'], input[type='tel'], textarea", function (event) {
    if (event.which != 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The second parameter after `'click'` should be a CSS selector, not a jQuery collection. Simply remove the `$()` around the string

Comment: To extend what @IliaG is saying...you are still trying to create a collection of elements that don't exist yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/on/

At the 1st argument, add `keypress` next to `click` for keypress event. Also you don't need to wrap the selectors around `$(`...`)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Assigning elements a common class is also good idea (Thanks @yaser for bringing this up!)

Comment: Ah - it was a typo on my part, I did have `keypress` instead of `click`. But, my error was wrapping the elements. Looking back, I should of in fact created a class and bound to the class as suggested. Seems like an obvious now. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing: Assign the result of `$(this)` to a variable, like `$this`. This is a common jQuery gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag == 'input' || tag == 'textarea') 
    {
      if (event.keyCode != 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Alternetively you can give them all a class and use this:

```
$('.commonclass').keypress(function(event){       
   if (event.keyCode != 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: you can't use `keypress()` to delegate. Will only work for existing elements

Comment: you're damn right @charlietfl, check the updated answer

Comment: think you side tracked...first solution was originally targeting correct elements...it is the second `keypress()` method that won't delegate for future elements

Comment: @Yaser - this is fantastic. Thank you very much for putting this together!